# Типобезопасные запросы trunc(date)

Tags: java, jpa, criteriabuilder

Сделал вот такой запрос:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> queryFilter = builder.createTupleQuery();

Root<MEg> root = queryFilter.from(MEg.class);

queryFilter.multiselect(root.get("dInp").alias("dInp"), builder.count(root.get("dInp")).alias("cnt"));
queryFilter.groupBy(root.get("dInp"));
queryFilter.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("dInp")));

List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
Predicate filterApps = builder.between(root.get("dInp").as(Date.class), search.getBegDate(), search.getEndDate());
predicateList.add(filterApps);
Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
predicateList.toArray(predicates);
queryFilter.where(predicates);

TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(queryFilter);
List<Tuple> t = tq.getResultList();
```

В результате он выдает такие данные:

```
{"dInp":"08.07.2016","cnt":1},
{"dInp":"08.07.2016","cnt":2},
{"dInp":"08.07.2016","cnt":1},
{"dInp":"08.07.2016","cnt":1},
{"dInp":"12.07.2016","cnt":1},
{"dInp":"13.07.2016","cnt":1},
{"dInp":"13.07.2016","cnt":1},
{"dInp":"13.07.2016","cnt":2}
```

как можно сделать что бы он выводил одну дату только 1 раз и посчитал их сумму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
queryFilter.multiselect(
                builder.function("trunc",
                        Date.class, root.get("dInp")).alias("dInp"),
                builder.count(builder.function("trunc",
                        Date.class, root.get("dInp"))).alias("cnt"));

        queryFilter.groupBy(builder.function("trunc", Date.class, root.get("dInp")));
        queryFilter.orderBy(builder.asc(builder.function("trunc", Date.class, root.get("dInp"))));


 filterApps = builder.between(
                    builder.function("trunc",
                    Date.class, root.get("dInp")).as(Date.class), search.getBegDate(), search.getEndDate());
            predicateList.add(filterApps);
```